# Does the TIGER geocoder intersect the polygons to match an address?

Tags: postgis, polygon, geocoding, intersection, tiger

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991330/how-does-the-google-geocoder-work) has a very good overwiew of how open source geocoders works.

1) Address normalization
2) String matching.
3) Interpolation.

It shows a simple case of how interpolation in made, taking as example a street segment that is supposed to contain houses between 300-400, just 
interpolating the position over the line.

[image]

Now my question here if the zip code is specified in the address and the street segment covers more than one zip code? is this consider during the interpolation? and if is, How it's done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary dataset that the postgis tiger geocoder uses is the edges (to provide the geometry) and addr table (for address range and zip).  If you look at the addr table it is broken such that each range has only one zip.  So depending on side of street (side = L or R), and the range, that is the zip that is used.